# "sudo ansible-playbook" command fails even with --user option

Tags: ansible, sudo

I've a user foo which is able to do passwordless ssh to A(self) and B. The playbook requires sudo access inside which I'm escalating with become and the below command is working fine.

```
ansible-playbook -i ../inventory.ini --user=foo --become --become-user=root echo_playbook.yml
```

But the above command is part of a shell script which doesn't have permission for foo. So when I use sudo to trigger that shell script, ansible is saying host unreachable. So I tried the ansible command with sudo as shown below and same. It showed host is unreachable.

```
sudo ansible-playbook -i ../inventory.ini --user=foo --become --become-user=root echo_playbook.yml
```

I agree that sudo is escalating the ansible-playbook to root. But I'm also providing the `--user` to tell ansible that "foo" user needs to be used for ssh.

Basically to access the playbook I need sudo. To connect to other servers I need foo user. To execute the actions inside the playbook (commands in playbook) I need sudo again (which I am using become for).

Am I doing anything wrong? Can anybody tell me the exact command for the ansible-playbook for the above scenario where ansible-playbook needs to run as `sudo ansible-playbook`?

Comment: Sudo doesn't affect users on other systems

Comment: @DanielFarrell But it changes the privileges to root in the same system and while trying ssh, ansible is using root and root's keys instead of foo's which is not available.

Comment: you say you're getting host unreachable.  But that's not likely to be affected by the user attempting the request. with or without sudo, host unreachable suggets a network error or the hostname might have been mis specified.  you should always include exact errors in your questions

Comment: Without sudo, ansible will run as foo and take the keys of foo for ssh which will work. With sudo, ansible will run as root and take the keys of root for ssh which is unavailable and ansible will throw a host unreachable error as it couldn't do a passwordless ssh.
The exat error will be `Error on A: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: `.
The above error is not coming when run without sudo. It's unlikely that when running with sudo the servers are going down.

Comment: you should set `sudo: yes` after `hosts: <host_name>` in ansible playbook. This will make sure that the tasks that are getting executed will use sudo if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on exactly where you're stuck.  I don't think you're confused between the remote user and the local user. If the playbook works as `foo`, and from what you describe, I can only guess that `~foo/.ssh/id_rsa` or another automatically provided key authenticates `foo`.  But you can generate a key for any user and allow it access to the remote `foo` if you'd prefer.  Or, you can run the playbook as another user.  It's up to you.  The only thing that won't work is relying on the environment or configuration of particular users and then not providing it.

> the above command is part of a shell script which doesn't have permission for foo.

What I'm hearing is that:

- a user `foo` can successfully run ansible job
- a script runs (under `root`?) that cannot run the ansible job

If you're happy with how ansible works for the `foo` user, you can switch to the `foo` user to run the ansible:

```
sudo -u foo ansible-playbook ...
```

If the script runs as root, sudo will always succeed.  Otherwise, you can [configure sudo to allow one user to access another](https://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access) for one command or more.

Comment: I followed kind of a similar approach only. I went with `su foo -c "ansible ..."` command as `sudo -u foo` will require a similar entry in sudoers file. Running the script with sudo, it already had root privileges and `su foo` for ansible didn't ask for password.